# how to efficiently convert Raw sql query to Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a raw SQL query

```sql
SELECT cc.name, pp.population
FROM population_table pp
WHERE pp.country_name IN (
    SELECT cc.name 
    FROM `countries` cc
)
GROUP BY pp.country_name
```

The above query gives the list of countries that are in `countries` table along with `population` value.

I'm trying to convert this query to eloquent by splitting the queries into two. I'm using this eloquent in database level.

```php
public function getCountriesWithPopulation() {
    $countryTable = Country::$TABLE_NAME;
    $populationTable = Population::$TABLE_NAME;

    $query1 = // eloquent query
    $query2 = // eloquent query
}
```

How can I convert the raw query into eloquent by splitting the queries?

---

### Edit:

SQL Query

```sql
SELECT country, region, area, pp.population
FROM population_table pp
FROM (
    SELECT cc.country, cc.region, cc.area 
    FROM `countries` cc
) 
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run two queries. Just consider it as a straight JOIN:

```sql
SELECT cc.name, pp.population
FROM population_table AS pp
JOIN `countries` AS cc 
    ON (cc.name = pp.country_name)
GROUP BY pp.country_name
```

And Eloquent has a built-in support for JOIN. In this case, also, the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary since only one country's `name` per `country` is ever retrieved.

Actually, though, if the database is in a reasonable state (there is 1:1 correspondence between `countries` and `population`) you would not even need `cc` at all. The country `name` is, unlikely enough, available in `pp` (it should rather be a foreign key into `countries`), so as things stand, you might just do:

```sql
SELECT country_name, population
FROM population_table;
```

Unless you have the `population` table storicized. Then things are easy for a `JOIN`, more difficult for Eloquent, and there is the possibility of a missing census year in `population`:

```sql
SELECT cc.name, pp.population
FROM population_table AS pp
JOIN `countries` AS cc
    ON (
        cc.name = pp.country_name AND 
        pp.year=$selectedYear
    )
GROUP BY pp.country_name
```

Comment: Thanks for briefing. Do this also working for the query mentioned in the edit part?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The way it works is, it will select all countries, then it will select those populations where the country is known.
This is equivalent to a JOINing of the populations with the countries. Actually, with a modern MySQL, the JOIN is *better* because the new default (ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) might not accept "GROUP BY pp.country_name" but require "GROUP BY cc.name, pp.population" unless aggregate functions are used. The straight JOIN does not need the GROUP BY, so it wouldn't be affected. Depending on table structures, cardinality and indexing, it might also be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Basen on your query,

```sql
SELECT cc.name, pp.population
FROM population_table pp
WHERE pp.country_name IN (SELECT cc.name FROM `countries` cc) 
GROUP BY pp.country_name
```

You can achieve the same result with Eloquent such as

```php
public function getCountriesWithPopulation()
{
    // get country names as array
    $countryNames = Country::pluck('name');

    // get your result
    $result = Population::whereIn('country_name', $countryNames)->groupBy('country_name');
}
```

Edit:

matiaslauriti's comment was right, you can directly use `pluck('name')` instead of `all()->pluck('name')` for efficiency and performance.

`Country::pluck('name')` will return all `name` column data in the country table, so that you can use later for filtering population data using `whereIn()`

`Population::whereIn('country_name', $countryNames)->groupBy('country_name')` will return all data in population table where column `country_name` is in `$countryNames` array. The query will be grouped by `country_name` column so that there is no country name duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the briefing, could you explain me for the query mentioned in the edit?

Comment: Never do `all()->pluck('name');`, always do `pluck('name');` directly, as `all` will get all rows (could be a lot of them) and then you are only getting `name` from each of them... a lot of memory wasted and PHP is doing this conversion from all data model to just name for each model...